# Sed back referencing

Tags: sed, backreference

I have a text file mountainList.txt with the following inside:

```
      Brasstown Bald, (summit),4784,feet,Union County
Rabun Bald, (summit),4696,feet,Rabun County
Dick's Knob, (summit),4620,feet,Rabun County
              Hightower Bald, (summit),4568,feet,Towns County
Wolfpen Ridge, (ridge high point),4561,feet,Towns and Union Counties 
     Blood Mountain, (summit),4458,feet,Union County
Tray Mountain, (summit), 4430,feet,Towns County
          Grassy Ridge, (ridge high point),4420,feet,Rabun County
Slaughter Mountain, (summit),4338,feet,Union County
Double Spring Knob, (summit),4280,feet,Rabun County
Coosa Bald, (summit),4280,feet,Union County
```

I'm trying to back reference to get just the mountain name and county(i.e. Brasstown Bald, Union County). I have a expression, but it doesn't work properly:

```
sed -E 's/(.+, )(.+),(\w+ Count[yies]+)/\1\3/' mountainList.txt
```

It does what I want, but only for the first line. Could someone explain why this is so?

Comment: you're missing a closing parenthesis `sed -E 's/(.+, )(.+),(\w+ Count[yies]+)/\1\3/' mountainList.txt`

Comment: Oh sorry, that was an error. I meant to include that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^\s*([^,]*),.*,.*,.*,(.*)\s*$/\1, \2/' file
```

Capture the first and last fields, using the `,` separator.

Comment: This does work! But why not enclose '.*\s*$' in the parentheses rather than just '.*'? And why not use the -E flag?

Comment: @Musilix if you want white space at the end of the last field, just use `.*`. In GNU sed either `-r` or `-E` invoke the same option, so use which ever you like or remove it and quote parens.

Answer (score 0):

Using your command, it seems to work

```
$ sed -E 's/(.+, )(.+),(\w+ Count[yies]+)/\1\3/' mountainList.txt
      Brasstown Bald, Union County
Rabun Bald, Rabun County
Dick's Knob, Rabun County
              Hightower Bald, Towns County
Wolfpen Ridge, (ridge high point),4561,feet,Towns and Union Counties 
     Blood Mountain, Union County
Tray Mountain, (summit), Towns County
          Grassy Ridge, Rabun County
Slaughter Mountain, Union County
Double Spring Knob, Rabun County
Coosa Bald, Union County
```

I'm using this version of sed:

```
$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Data is structured, so an **awk** solution works as well:

```
$ awk -F, '{ sub(/^ */,"",$1); print $1,"-", $5 }' input.txt
Brasstown Bald - Union County
Rabun Bald - Rabun County
Dick's Knob - Rabun County
Hightower Bald - Towns County
Wolfpen Ridge - Towns and Union Counties
Blood Mountain - Union County
Tray Mountain - Towns County
Grassy Ridge - Rabun County
Slaughter Mountain - Union County
Double Spring Knob - Rabun County
Coosa Bald - Union County
```